# Input não está sendo checado via php

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, input

Eu tenho o seguinte `input`:

```
<input type="radio" id="isgift0" name="isgift" value="0" class="arredondado" <?php if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getInputMensagem() == 1){echo "checked='checked'"} ?> />
```

Tentando checar ele via `php` não está dando certo, pois o mesmo não está vindo checado. Fazendo isso via `jQuery`, ele é checado corretamente, porém demora muito para executar isso e acaba afetando na funcionalidade da página.

Checagem via `jQuery`:

```
$j(document).ready(function () {
     <?php 
        if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getInputMensagem() == 1) {
     ?>
          $j('#isgift0').prop('checked','checked');
          $j('#isgift0').click();
     <?php
        }
     ?>
});
```

Queria saber se teria alguma maneira de fazer essa mesma checagem, mas de uma maneira mais rápida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O modo que você fez usando o PHP está correto, apenas esqueceu de fechar a linha do código com `;`, que ficaria assim (como citado na outra resposta, pode-se usar apenas `checked`):

```
<input type="radio" id="isgift0" name="isgift" value="0" class="arredondado" <?php if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getInputMensagem() == 1){echo 'checked';} ?> />
```

Alternativamente, você pode checar o `radio` de forma *instantânea* usando **JavaScript puro** em vez de jQuery com `document ready` (que demora mais para carregar). Basta inserir um `script` logo após o elemento:

```
<input type="radio" id="isgift0" name="isgift" value="0" class="arredondado" />
<?php
if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getInputMensagem() == 1){
   echo '<script>document.getElementById("isgift0").checked = true;</script>';
}
?>
```

**Por que eu digo "de forma instantânea"?**

Como a página é carregada de cima *pra baixo*, o interpretador JavaScript do navegador já estará pronto e irá executar o `script` logo após carregar o elemento `radio` em questão, *checando* ele imediatamente antes do resto da página ser carregada.

Mas a primeira opção usando só PHP ainda sim é a melhor, pois é direta e não irá precisar adicionar mais código na página.

Comment: Excelente explicação. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Matheus se quer via PHP faça assim:

```
<?php
$checkedisgift0 = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getInputMensagem() == 1 ? 'checked' : '';
?>

<input type="radio" id="isgift0" name="isgift" value="0" class="arredondado" <?php echo $checkedisgift0; ?> />
```

E remova a parte jQuery que criou só pra isto, então quando tiver a sessão `==1` irá exibir algo como:

```
<input type="radio" id="isgift0" name="isgift" value="0" class="arredondado" checked />
```

> Em html5 não é necessário `checked=checked` basta `checked`.

Ainda sim é bom notar que os elementos não podem repitir os IDs e o tipo rádio geralmente é usado para multipla escolha, se existiri apenas um rádio com o mesmo `name` (name="isgift") então é preferivel usar o `type="checkbox"`